# What is the global scope of <script> tag?

Tags: javascript

I had made flag and made my previous question deleted because of missunderstanding.

I'm working on a classic asp project.

let's say you have so many `<script></script>`  tags in your code.

For instance:

line 10: `<script> ..function 1 definition here..</script>`

line 200: `<script> .. function 2 definition here..</script>`

line 5000: `<script> ..function 3 definition here..</script>`

also at line 6000: I have another  tag which is trying to call function1.

is that possible without using *.js file ?

**For instance:**

line 6000:

```
<script> function1(); </script>
```

Those scripts are not defined in `<head>` tag.

I know its not useful but I need to know is there any way of it or not.

Hope its more clear now!

Comment: Yes, that's possible, why didn't you test it ?

Comment: I believe so, since you do not need to use information that are not generated earlier.

Comment: @dystroy: can you please show how to do that? I have tried so many ways but no luck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just like you write it in your question is OK. And calling functions defined in other files is terribly useful : you wouldn't have any library without this ability.

Comment: @curiousBoy: It will be more beneficial for you if you show us exactly what you've tried, and for us to explain what is wrong with it. If you just take code that we provide you might not learn how to write it on your own next time.

Comment: @MarkHildreth: Of course, definitely agree with you. But I guess, I was trying something wrong. I would like to share my code, but I believe it doesn't make sense for any one. Simply its like my question, but it 9k lines and maybe there are 30 different script tags. I think its better to try to get help with the simplified question. I do appreciate your suggestion tho.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

anything inside the script tags gets run immediately. if you define `function a()` in your first script element, then it will add a function called `a` to your global namespace.  any javascript you execute later on in other script elements will have access to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function a() {
       alert('hi');
   }
</script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    a();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is possible, assuming `function1` is in the global scope (e.g. not in a wrapper function/self-invoking function).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible . You just need to define it in global namespace. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp) is the link which should give you an idea and better understanding. It also includes very simple examples.