# Call function in one javascript in other script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a ASPX page.. and my script isn't working

please find the updated code below:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void settxtSymbol(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch ((Timer1.Interval / 3) % 3)
        {
            case 0: txtSymbol.Value = "GOOG";
                break;
            case 1: txtSymbol.Value = "MICR";
                break;
            case 2: txtSymbol.Value = "YHOO";
                break;
        }
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this ,this.GetType(), "script", 
            "javascript:{var txtSymbol = document.getElementById(\"txtSymbol\");
             window.location = \"default.aspx?s=\"" + txtSymbol.Value + ";}", true);
    }
</script>
```

I need to call SendRequest from settextSymbol function

Comment: protected void settextSymbol(object sender, System.EventArgs e) seems like a server side code rite?

Comment: And what is strong text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494247/is-there-any-way-of-calling-javascript-function-in-script-tag-which-has-define

Comment: @iJay yes its a server side code...

That was a mistake

Comment: @MarikkaniChelladurai The questions are completely different...for me the issue is one script is server side and other is client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it make a separate `.js` file, Name it as you want let say `main.js`. Then you can put that method in the `main.js` file you have created. And just include that `main.js file` in your html file within the `script tag` where you want to call in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you merge the two inside a single `<Script>` and put before `</body>` tag.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        /// <summary>
        /// This function will be called when user clicks the Get Quotes button.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Always return false.</returns>

        function SendRequest() {
                var txtSymbol = document.getElementById("txtSymbol");
                // Refresh the page.
                window.location = "default.aspx?s=" + txtSymbol.value;
                return false;
        }

        // if its not a sever side event then you should consider using this
        protected void settextSymbol(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            switch ((Timer1.Interval / 3) % 3)
            {
                case 0: txtSymbol.Value = "GOOG";
                    break;
                case 1: txtSymbol.Value = "MICR";
                    break;
                case 2: txtSymbol.Value = "YHOO";
                    break;
            }
           Sendrequest();
        }
```

If Set text Symbol is sever side code then you should considering doing this way

```
 protected void settextSymbol(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            switch ((Timer1.Interval / 3) % 3)
            {
                case 0: txtSymbol.Value = "GOOG";
                    break;
                case 1: txtSymbol.Value = "MICR";
                    break;
                case 2: txtSymbol.Value = "YHOO";
                    break;
            }
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript(setTextSymbol,GetType(),"myScript","javascript:Sendrequest();",true);
        }
```

Comment: I just saw, that It looks like a ServerSide code I hve edited

Comment: @AmitRanjan.. indeed a unique solution..but its bit confusing..RegisterStartUpScript only takes two arguments and also I don't understand what is key and script

Comment: @user1818702 good point. Actually I was bit confused. Whether it was Page, ClientScript or ScriptManager.. Thanks for pointing out mistake

Comment: Thanx...but the code still isnt running..Please find my updated code on main question

Answer (score 0):

settextSymbol looks like server side code.

Your server side code will be already have executed by the time the JavaScript (client side) function exist.

Your server side function can generate JavaScript output to the HTML result that can call your client side script, but you can not call JavaScript from the server before the server side rendering is fiished.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `SendRequest()` from `settextSymbol()`

If you are having problem, try remove `runat="server"` from script tag.