# How can I get the JSON data between the script tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parsing

I want to fetch an html page and then parse it with domParser. then I want to pull the array between the script tags inside this html file.
How can I access the imageUrl in the script tag inside this html file?

```
fetch(geturl)
           .then(function(response) {
               return response.text();
           })
           .then(function(html) {
               var parser = new DOMParser();
               var document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
               // here
           })
           .catch(function(error) {
               console.log("Error: ", error);
           });
```

```
<script>
let testArray = {"test":"138","test2":95,"imageUrl":"hrththterg122323"};
</script>
```

Comment: use regular expressions or regex to match pattern

Comment: @JoyDey When I run it on the site, I can access it as you said, but when I do it with fetch, I get a not defined error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object defined in script tag gets initialized immediately. All other js that is initialized or run later has access to the defined object.

```
fetch(geturl)
       .then(function(response) {
           return response.text();
       })
       .then(function(html) {
           var parser = new DOMParser();
           var document = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
           
           console.log(testArray.imageUrl);
       })
       .catch(function(error) {
           console.log("Error: ", error);
       });
```

Check
[What is the global scope of <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494247/what-is-the-global-scope-of-script-tag)

Comment: Failed to fetch page:  ReferenceError: testArray is not defined

Comment: When I run it on the site, I can access it as you said, but when I do it with fetch, I get a not defined error.