# What JS scope is used by <script> tag?

Tags: javascript

I am writing in my html some JS between `<script>` tag:

```js
console.log('exist in ? scope', foo !== undefined)
console.log('exist in window scope', window.foo !== undefined)
console.log('exist in document scope', document.foo !== undefined)
console.log('exist in globalThis scope', globalThis.foo !== undefined)
```

```html
<script>
  class FooBar {}; 
  const foo = new FooBar()
</script>
```

In my JS Development console, I can find both `FooBar` and `foo`.

I would expect them to be in `window`, `document`, `globalThis`, and be able to access with `window.foo`, but it's not.

In which scope are kept those variables ?

Comment: Why `document` for example could access to a variable that isn't in the document, aka the html page ? I don't understand why you expected that

Comment: Code from script tags is put in a global scope. [What is the global scope of <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494247/what-is-the-global-scope-of-script-tag) - it's a good thing that not everything adds to the window object or that would be really crowded.

Comment: So what is global scope ? How does the console   read from it ?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862268/1169519) to see the difference between variable scope and object properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `script` tag is just that...An HTML tag. As such, it doesn't have a scope because it's not JavaScript, it's HTML. What the `script` element does for your is allows the HTML parser to "stand down" and have the JavaScript interpreter take over. The JS within the `script` tag will execute according to standard JS rules. That means that references will be evaluated via the normal scope chain process.

In essence, everything in JS is global unless you code it to be otherwise.

Keep in mind that `window` is not part of JavaScript. It's an API provided by browsers, so when we talk about "global", we are not always talking about `window`. In node.js, for example, there is no `window` or `document`, but there still is a global scope. So, in JS, you can have globals, but that doesn't mean that they are automatically attached as properties of the `window` object.

- Globals in JS are accessible by simply stating their reference name.
- Any HTML element with an `ID` attribute will become a property of the
  `window` object.
- Any JS property explicitly created as part of the `window` object
  will be available via the `window` object.
- Any HTML element that is part of the page that is loaded will be
  accessible via a DOM API (i.e., `document.querySelector`,
  `document.getElementById`).

This is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385835/invocation-context-and-execution-context-in-javascript-are-we-talking-of-th/41386097#41386097) from a while back that talks about the "scope chain" and how it works.

As @Teemu points out in the comments below, when you have a `script type="module"`, things work a bit differently. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) for more details.

Comment: Would it be worth of mention, that scripts type of module are behaving differently? I know OP didn't specifically ask about modules, but for future readers perhaps.

Comment: @Teemu That's a good point. I think that rather than explain that here though, I will edit to make sure that it's understood that they are a bit different.

Comment: In this case, how can I attach a variable to global scope from within a class ? And how can I access a global variable using a string ?

Comment: Use StackOverflows search and just type in that exact question. For example here: [Define a global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function). The function can also be in a class. The variable must have been declared beforehand.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa If you read the link in my answer, you'll see that you don't define a global from within a class. JavaScript is lexically scoped. This means that *where* you declare your variable determines what its scope is.